# WPF - Hide Selected Item / Text Box portion from Combobox Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm looking for a way to hide the Selected Item / Textbox portion of the wpf combobox, leaving only the drop down button so users can still interact with the list.

I cannot find a property to toggle this behaviour, I was curious to know if there is a way to change visibility of certain portions of this control?

If anyone has any suggestions, It'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your `ComboBox` editable? Could you please include your current code/markup in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - To use the below code you will need to use ComboBoxStyleWithoutText as a style on your combobox

To achieve this I had to re-create a combo-box and edit the template itself whilst tweaking the individual styles to suit the colour scheme of our app.

This is the result
[image]

In the application
[image]

Please feel free to use the code below, it likely has some custom colours I've used from other dictionaries (Change these to whatever suits your app)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Shared.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Colours.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!-- SimpleStyles: ComboBox -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" 
                 TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                CornerRadius="2"
                Background="{StaticResource ScreenBackgroundBrush}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource GridBorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="2" />
        <Border Grid.Column="0"
                CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"
                Margin="1"
                Background="{StaticResource ScreenBackgroundBrush}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource GridBorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" />
        <Path x:Name="Arrow"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Fill="{StaticResource SecondaryControlBrush}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" 
                 Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                    Property="Background" 
                    Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderRowBackgroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" 
                 Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border"
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderRowBackgroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" 
                 Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" 
                    Value="0.25" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                    Property="Background" 
                    Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                    Property="BorderBrush" 
                    Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                    Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" 
                    Property="Fill" 
                    Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" 
                 TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
            Focusable="False" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyleWithoutText" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"                 Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"                 Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"                 Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"                 Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"                 Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth"                 Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight"                 Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Background"                 Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" 
                                  Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                                  Grid.Column="2" 
                                  Focusable="false" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                  ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" 
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" 
                                      Margin="3,3,3,3" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                             Style="{x:Null}" 
                             Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                             Margin="3,3,3,3" 
                             Focusable="True" 
                             Visibility="Hidden" 
                             IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                    <Popup Name="Popup" 
                           Placement="Bottom" 
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" 
                           AllowsTransparency="True" 
                           Focusable="False" 
                           PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid Name="DropDown" 
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" 
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" 
                                    Background="{StaticResource TextBoxBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="2" 
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" />
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,2,2" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" 
                                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" 
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" 
                                Property="MinHeight" 
                                Value="95" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" 
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                                Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" 
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" 
                                Value="false" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" 
                             Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" 
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" 
                                Property="CornerRadius" 
                                Value="4" />
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" 
                                Property="Margin" 
                                Value="0,2,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" 
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" 
                                Value="false" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                                Property="Visibility" 
                                Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" 
                                Property="Visibility" 
                                Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" 
       TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" 
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" 
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" 
            Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" 
            Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" 
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" 
            Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" 
            Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" 
                                  Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                                  Grid.Column="2" 
                                  Focusable="false" 
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                  ClickMode="Press">
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" 
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" 
                                      Margin="3,3,23,3" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                             Style="{x:Null}" 
                             Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                             Margin="3,3,23,3" 
                             Focusable="True" 
                             Visibility="Hidden" 
                             IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                    <Popup Name="Popup" 
                           Placement="Bottom" 
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" 
                           AllowsTransparency="True" 
                           Focusable="False" 
                           PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Grid Name="DropDown" 
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" 
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" 
                                    Background="{StaticResource TextBoxBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="2" 
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" />
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" 
                                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" 
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" 
                                Property="MinHeight" 
                                Value="95" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" 
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                                Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" 
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" 
                                Value="false" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" 
                             Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" 
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" 
                                Property="CornerRadius" 
                                Value="4" />
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" 
                                Property="Margin" 
                                Value="0,2,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" 
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" 
                                Value="false" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                                Property="Visibility" 
                                Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" 
                                Property="Visibility" 
                                Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!-- SimpleStyles: ComboBoxItem -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" 
       TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" 
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" 
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Background" 
            Value="{StaticResource ScreenBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" 
            Value="{StaticResource PrimaryTextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Border Name="Border" 
                        Padding="2" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" 
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowSelectedBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="CornerRadius"
                                Value="2" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" 
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                                Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to hide the text part is probably to set the `Width` of the `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Width="20" />
```

Otherwise, you could always define your own custom `ControlTemplate` and set the `Template` property to this one but this requires some more effort.

Comment: Editing the template ended up being the desired option - definitely more effort haha